# Contact Form, PHP form appears when I hit the submit button

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have been trying to get my contact form in my html to work for a while now but it is not working at all.

When I enter in the details required and hit submit button I get sent to my PHP script.

My PHP code (excluding my email address):

```
<?php


$data['error'] = false;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if( empty($name) ){
    $data['error'] = 'Please enter your name.';
}else if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){
    $data['error'] = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
}else if( empty($subject) ){
    $data['error'] = 'Please enter your subject.';
}else if( empty($message) ){
    $data['error'] = 'The message field is required!';
}else{

    $formcontent="From: $name\nSubject: $subject\nEmail: $email\nMessage: $message";



    $recipient = "Email@outlook.com";

    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

    if( mail($recipient, $name, $formcontent, $mailheader) == false ){
        $data['error'] = 'Sorry, an error occured!';
    }else{
        $data['error'] = false;
    }

}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Here is my contact HTML:

```
             <div class='contact-form'>

               <form id='contact-form' data-toggle='validator' method='post' action='mail.php'>

                 <div id='contact-form-result'></div>

                 <div class='row'>

                   <div class='col-md-6'>
                     <div class='form-group'>

                       <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Name' name='name' required>
                       <div class='help-block with-errors'></div>

                     </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class='col-md-6'>
                     <div class='form-group'>

                       <input type='email' class='form-control' placeholder='Email' name='email' required>
                       <div class='help-block with-errors'></div>

                     </div>
                   </div>

                 </div>

                 <div class='form-group'>

                   <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Subject' name='subject' required>
                   <div class='help-block with-errors'></div>

                 </div>

                 <div class='form-group'>

                   <textarea class='form-control' placeholder='Message' name='message' rows='5' required></textarea>
                   <div class='help-block with-errors'></div>

                 </div>

                 <div class='form-group text-center'>
                   <button type='submit' class='btn-custom btn-color'>
                     Send Message
                   </button>
                 </div>

               </form>

             </div>


           </div>
```

Would Appreciate some help with this please.

Comment: The code looks fine. Please look into SMTP configurations for your machine/server.

Comment: how do I do that please?

Comment: "It is not working" is not a clear statement.
If you cannot check your SMTP configuration, you cannot check the logs of the mail server neither, I bet. 
A guess of mine is that you need your SMTP credentials of the web hoster's SMTP server to send mails. You can do that with a dedicated SMTP class that also can write log files into you home directory.